# Neo4j: OutOfMemoryError when running cypher query from neo4j-shell

Tags: shell, neo4j, out-of-memory, cypher

I have a Neo4j database with about 130K nodes and probably somewhere between 17M relationships. My computer running Windows 10 has 16GB of RAM, 10GB (maximum) of which are allocated to the Neo4j-shell heap.

I want to run a query using the neo4j-shell from the command prompt and redirect the results to a csv file. The command I’m using for that is:

```
Neo4jShell -v -file query.cql > results.csv
```

Where the query is of the form:

```
MATCH (subject)-[:type1]->(intNode1:label)<-[:type2]-(intNode2:label)<-[:type3]-(object) RETURN subject.property1, object.property1;
```

The problem is that whenever I run this query, I get an OutOfMemory error (see error message at the bottom).

Does anyone have advice for how to run a query like this successfully? I feel like 10GB of RAM should be enough for a query like this given the size of the graph DB.

The error message I get is:

```
ERROR (-v for expanded information):
        Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
java.rmi.ServerError: Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$2.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.interpretLine(Unknown Source)
        at org.neo4j.shell.impl.AbstractClient.evaluate(AbstractClient.java:149)
        at org.neo4j.shell.impl.AbstractClient.evaluate(AbstractClient.java:133)
        at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.executeCommandStream(StartClient.java:393)
        at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.grabPromptOrJustExecuteCommand(StartClient.java:372)
        at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.startRemote(StartClient.java:330)
        at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.start(StartClient.java:196)
        at org.neo4j.shell.StartClient.main(StartClient.java:135)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution when I hade this problem was to add this line on the end of neo4j.properties

```
# Default values for the low-level graph engine

    cache_type=none
    neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=50M
    neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=500M
    neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=100M
    neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=100M
    neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=0M
```

also try to increase java in neo4j-wrapper.conf this line

```
#wrapper.java.initmemory=2048
#wrapper.java.maxmemory=2048
```

One more thing do you have index on node that you query?

Comment: I just used the Neo4j-import tool to import the database. I'm not sure if that creates indexes or if I need to do it manually? Thanks for the suggestions. I'll try them when I get to my home computer and see if it works.

Comment: Also, how much RAM does your computer have? Just so I know what to set my memory settings.

Comment: I add this#wrapper.java.initmemory=2048
#wrapper.java.maxmemory=2048

Comment: Right, but that allocation is dependent on how much total RAM your computer has. That's what I was asking.

Comment: For machine with 16GB of RAM i use those settings with 2048

Answer (score 0):

You can provide more heap for Neo4jShell (use `JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx4G -Xms4G -Xmn1G` environment variable).

Did you try to run your query with profile? I presume you span up billions of paths as you don't have any restrictions.

You missed a label on subject and object, which cause the query planner to run a full-graph-scan.

```
MATCH (subject:label)-[:type1]->(intNode1:label)
               <-[:type2]-(intNode2:label)
               <-[:type3]-(object:label) 
WITH distinct subject, object
RETURN subject.property1, object.property1;
```

You should reduce the in-between cardinality and also the output cardinality.

```
MATCH (subject:label)-[:type1]->(intNode1:label)
               <-[:type2]-(intNode2:label)
WITH distinct subject, intNode2
MATCH (intNode2)<-[:type3]-(object:label) 
WITH distinct subject, object
RETURN subject.property1, object.property1;
```

even better would be:

```
MATCH (subject:label)-[:type1]->(intNode1:label)
               <-[:type2]-(intNode2:label)
WITH intNode2, collect(distinct subject) as subjects
MATCH (intNode2)<-[:type3]-(object:label) 
WITH distinct object, subjects
UNWIND subjects as subject
RETURN subject.property1, object.property1;
```

Comment: Right, I changed the heap size to 10GB for the shell but that's pretty much as high as I can go on my computer. I left the subject and object without a label on purpose because I don't know what they should be beforehand. The goal of the query is to find all unique combinations of subject and object involved in the pattern specified and return their property. Also, I didn't run the query with a profile. How would that help exactly?